# Cannot determine abi of native library in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am using a third-party .jar for which I have created a bindings project which compiles correctly. The .jar uses a .so native library for much of its functionality. I can't get this to be installed by the .apk . While deploying I'm getting an error: `Cannot determine abi of native library MainActivity.cs`. I have added the .so files in their corresponding folders with build action as Android native library and also as always copy.
My Target Framework is Android 4.1 and xamarin-studio version is 5.9.4

[image]

Comment: the same error message also appears if you have mips native libraries in your project. Maybe this helps anybody coming here with that message. I'm only adding this as a comment because it doesn't seem to be the reason in your case.

Comment: Has this been solved? I am having the same issue and would like to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Clear unsupported SO files from library project obj>(debug|release)>library imports>jni and same action for main project project>obj>library imports>library>library project imports>jni